# Creating a static method that meshes two strings together

Tags: java

We recently started learning about static methods and for this assignment we are making a "String Helper" program that creates a few static methods that modify strings, and this is the task for one of them:

`meshStrings`: This method takes in two strings via parameters, meshes them together, and returns the meshed strings.  Meshing alternates the each character in the first string with every character in the next string.  If there are not enough characters to fully mesh then the rest will be appended to the end.  For instance if the two strings were `"harp"` and `"fiddle"` the returned string will be `hfairdpdle`.

Here's the start of what I have, I don't have much:

```
public class StringHelper {
public static String meshStrings (String string1, String string2)
{

}
```

**Driver class:**

```
public class StringHelperTester {

public static void main (String[] args)
{
    System.out.print(StringHelper.meshStrings("fiddle", "harp"));
}
```

I assume you'll have some type of for loop that prints out the `charAt` length of each string but I'm not exactly sure the best way to set it up. Help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the best way to enchance your skills is to just try ...

```
public static String meshStrings (String string1, String string2) {
        StringBuffer buff = new StringBuffer();
        int max = Math.max(string1.length(), string2.length());
        for(int i = 0; i < max; i++) {
            if(i < string1.length()) {
                buff.append(string1.charAt(i));
            }
            if(i < string2.length()) {
                buff.append(string2.charAt(i));
            }
        }
        return buff.toString();
    }
```

KISS : keep it simple and stupid. then you can enhance this code if you want, it's not optimal.

Comment: Awesome thank you for the help! But I have never heard of this "StringBuffer" before so I am unsure exactly what it does. Also I haven't seen the .append method either. Do you or someone else mind elaborating please?

Comment: If you are learning Java, use an IDE like Eclipse that have Javadoc and autocompletion working well.
Usual string cannot be modified after allocation s = s1 + s2 is an new allocation. StringBuffer, no matter how it's implemented, is optimised to create string by appending char/ other strings.